# Using MS project vba on an excel workbook, i want to move a worksheet to the leftmost tab

Tags: ms-project

This is what I have so far

```
Sub SetupExcel(ByRef xlApp As Excel.Application, ByRef xlbook As Excel.Workbook)

    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
    Set xlbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
    Dim xlsheet As Excel.worksheet         
End Sub


sub Main_routine
    Call SetupExcel(xlApp, xlbook)
    call CreateTaskGraphics()
    ..... create a bunch of additional tabs in this workbook
    goto Exit_Here:


Exit_Here
xlApp.Worksheets("Task Graphics").Select
xlbook.Sheets("Task Graphics").Move Before:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count)`**  "<---- this is failing
..... closing statements
End Sub
```

So, this consists of many subs and a main routine. The CreateTaskGraphics routine create a tab and places text and buttons on it. The only thing failing is the next to last statement 
in the "Exit_Here" section where I want to move the "Task Graphics" tab to be leftmost in the workbook. I have used every combination I can think of to preceed the Sheets("Task Graphics")...  statement, such as xlBook,  xlWorkbook, xlsheet, xlapp, etc.  I cannot find any combination that works.Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

To move a worksheet to the beginning (e.g. left-most) position:

```
xlbook.Sheets("Task Graphics").Move Before:=xlbook.Sheets(1)
```

To add it as the left-most sheet in the first place:

```
Set xlsheet = xlbook.Worksheets.Add(Before:=xlbook.Worksheets(1))
```

When using the Sheets or Worksheets collection, remember to specify the workbook object; otherwise the active workbook is presumed which might not be what was intended.